# How to center navigation bar using css?

Tags: html, css

Hi im having trouble with centering the nav on this draft im making for a client.

Here is the link http://cjdrafts.info/germanserviceshop/

Please help thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a professional, still learning coding and found a way to fix your issue.

What I did is commented the float left for .menu-wrapper

```css
#Top_bar .menu_wrapper {
  /* float: left; 
  z-index: 201;*/
}
```

Then defined 650px width and set the left and right margin to auto

```css
.header-stack #Top_bar .menu_wrapper {
  clear: both;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 650px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Set `width` for `menu_wrapper`

```css
#Top_bar .menu_wrapper {
    z-index: 201;
    width: 650px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

remove `float`, set fixed `width` and set `margin: auto`.

2. Use `display: inline-block` instead of `float` for `li`

```css
#Top_bar .menu > li {
    margin: 0;
    z-index: 203;
    display: block;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

and:

```css
#Top_bar .menu_wrapper {
    float: left;
    z-index: 201;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
}
```

set `100% width` for parent and use `text-align: center`.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.

Doing the edits on a browser it does work but for some reason when i placed the css codes in the theme style sheet. Nothing work, i tried both solutions.

What seems to be the problem? I have been on this for atleast 7 days now.

I actually have a solution which is to use a menu plugin but this will be my last option.

Comment: To fix the issue i used a menu plugin but the thing is it removed the sticky effect while scrolling down.